# "think up a sentence", make up a sentence" or "make a sentence"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which phrasal verb is the most appropriate for the following sentence.

> Now that I have already learnt these words, I want you to **think up**/**make up**/**make** a few sentence with them.

I guess it is obvious that *think up* and *make up* mean the same in the sentence, but what about *make*?
Is there a difference between the phrases in the context? Which fits the context the best?

Comment: Note that it should be *learned* and *sentences*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now that **you** have already learnt these words, I want you to think up/make up/make a few sentence with them.

All the choices are understandable.

"make up" is probably the best. It means to invent a story.

"make" is a very generic word. It's correct. However, a bit abrupt and short here.

"think up" - notice in the dictionary it says "informal". If you are in a casual setting, then it's ok.